# What happens to albumin level in COVID-19 patient?

Tags: covid-19, liver

As we all know that albumin is a negative inflammatory phase reactant. In severe inflammation, the level of albumin goes down. In one of our reviews, we found that hypoalbuminemia is occurring in greater than 60% of the COVID-19 participants and the risk ratio of increase is greater in severe as compared to non-severe patients [60% prevalence](https://www.researchsquare.com/article/rs-37723/v1). But a published report from Lancet Gastroenterology and hepatology is reporting a 6% prevalence of hypoalbuminemia [Lancet study](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/langas/article/PIIS2468-1253(20)30126-6/fulltext).

What are the prevalence of hypoalbuminemia in your respective healthcare settings among COVID-19 patients? Is it a routine that you encounter? Can we take this hypoalbuminemia as a surrogate marker for severity of COVID-19?

Declaration of interest: I am a part of the author of the first link. The question is for scientific clarification in the forum.